# How can I most effectively farm Pixels?

Tags: starbound

I need a lot of Pixels to craft the various shiny weapons and armor that I have my eye on. However, the only ways that I can find to acquire Pixels are by killing enemies repeatedly, and by finding capsules underground. Neither method seems particularly quick, and frequent combat has its own associated risks.

Is there a better way? What is the fastest way to earn Pixels?

Comment: Once you do get higher level armor and weapons, I've noticed higher level monsters generally drop way more pixels than on the starting planet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Exploring the surface for large buildings can prove quite fruitful, as many of the chests and containers therein will contain large caches of pixels.  Take them.  All of them.  As of right now (shortly after the Frustrated Koala update), NPCs don't even get mad if you take their stuff from their containers.

If you cant' find such structures easily, there's another way to find large pixel caches.

Dig deeper down.

The world I am on has a huge underground cavern that has tons and TONS of capsules full of pixels.  dig down deep enough, and you'll start running into them all over the place.

This area is dangerous though, so be prepared.

For extra bits, make sure you kill monsters with a strong Melee weapon, which provides a high chance of them dropping bits (with ranged weapons, the chance for bits to drop is lower due to a higher chance to drop meat and leather instead).

Comment: This isn't quite true. I quite often have monsters drop pixels when killed with a ranged weapon.

Comment: @SaintWacko I've noticed this too, but only after the most recent update.  Changing my answer to reflect this.

Comment: AFAIK it's only more likely to drop leather or meat then you use Bow in particular, not any ranged weapon.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the refinery to turn excess ore into pixels fairly effectively.  To get this, you will need the tier 2 crafting station, which you can only access after defeating the first boss.  This is, however, a very effective way to get extra bits out of excess ore.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the processor is and how you use it?

Comment: @sterno Sorry Refinery. It converts ores into pixels.

Comment: @Sterno the refinery is a tier 2 product, you need to defeat the first boss and make the t2 crafting station from the item it drops before you can make the refinery. If you don't have that, the refinery isn't available to you yet.

Answer (score 6):

Search for a Sewer, but don't kill the **po golems** , search the whole sewer and lead all the po golems to one spot.

If the po golems can't hit you, they will start throwing small versions of **The po**
Dig a 4/6 wide gab between you and the po golems so the small po's fall in.
The small po's can be killed easy and you can collect the pixels quite easy!

*Make sure the range attacks of the golems can't hit you by placing one block in front of their face*

[image: Pixel farming in sewers]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind slaughtering NPC - killing guards yelds quite a lot of pixels. Kill everyone you see. Guards with sniper rifles can be dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Kill everything you see and pick all the ores that you find, and then turn the ores into pixels in the refinery and voila!

Answer (score 1):

Head to the highest sector you can currently access, then look for a group of planets that are all desert. Pull out your pickaxe, and start looking for large sections of either soft sand, or gravel.
Dig straight down, and as the sand and gravels falls, any ore that was trapped inside it will fall down and be collected, it's like your sitting at the bottom of a funnel collecting all the ore that falls. When you run out of sand/gravel, find a new place.
When you get bored, go and put the crazy amounts of ores that you've collected into your refinery/refineries, and watch the pixels pour in.

Answer (score 1):

An effective way of passively gathering pixels is to build a structure with a bunch of turrets on it in an untamed area. For best results, the turret weapons should outclass the planet you're on. Hang around nearby and attract monsters periodically, then lead them back to your turret firing squad and pick up the remains.

Disclaimer: this is based on my experience of creating an apartment complex for NPCs on a relatively dangerous planet. I'm not sure whether the proximity of civilian NPCs has an influence on this equation. Also, in my case the tiers of the planet and of the turret weapons are pretty close, which requires me and the civilian NPCs to take a hand in the defense. My guess is that on a lower-tier planet, turrets killing monsters by themselves will make for an overall more efficient process, but the higher your level relative to the monsters, the less rewarding it will be, obviously.

Using this setup, in ten minutes I gather over a thousand pixels. However, the turrets themselves obviously represent a significant initial investment, and turrets can't be re-positioned.

Comment: In ten minutes of gameplay, I earn 1k pixels just by looting chests, selling stuff or doing quests without focusing on gaining pixels. I'd probably rather use this method to farm monster loot like RAM sticks.

Comment: @TomášZato Psst ... check the date, this was way pre-1.0.

Comment: Okey, and? Afaik answers on SE are supposed to solve problem as good as possible. This one does not. Do you expect every visitor to compare dates before he starts reading every answer?

Comment: This is still an answer, the pixel amounts just differ these days.

Comment: You should really avoid being so defensive in reactions to a comment. I never said this is not an answer, if I thought so I would downvote and flag this post. I said that this method is (no longer) effective, which is true. I also said that on Stack Exchange, it is irrelevant when was the answer posted - that's also true. And I only commented that, because you for some reason needed to point the date-time out.

Answer (score 1):

The current best way to make pixels is by selling space station transponders. Their value is 150000 pixels and they sell for 30000.

You need ores to acquire them. So the strategy is going to a asteroid field and mine copper, silver, gold in abundance.

Then you need to mine titanium but you can buy half of the bars from the outpost and still be profitable

Answer (score 0):

All these ways of taking ores have a risk of dying. I have a better way that COULD kill you but only if you're about to die.

Make a large (30 x 10 is good) room, make sure there's no light and monsters will spawn. And you know they're coming! In 1 hour I got 1,450 pixels!

Answer (score 0):

Farm. I mean Actually farm crops. They give you tons of money of little effort. Especially crops that grow more of it self(like pearlpeas). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For the best gain *over time*, I focused on farming this two products:

- Rice - **sels for 24/pc**
- Silk (crafted from 4 [Silk Fibre](http://starbounder.org/Silk_Fibre) at [Sewing Machine](http://starbounder.org/Sewing_Machine)) **- sels for 40/pc** which is 10 per one Silk Fibre item.

Both those can be sold using [Terramart Shipments](http://starbounder.org/Terramart_Shipments) which gives you twice the normal price. Both are very convenient for farming.

- Rice does not need replanting, so all you need is one sprinkler for about 40 plants
- Silk fibre just needs you to place [Moth Trap](http://starbounder.org/Moth_Trap). You can even place them in your ship.

Of course, since I already have Terramart Shipments I also throw in any excess produces of my farm.

This probably isn't fastest method to gain lot of pixels but by the time you have build Heating EPP upgrade, you will no longer worry about pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Just retry the [Great Sovereign Temple](http://starbounder.org/The_Great_Sovereign_Temple) mission. You can find a Valkyrie Helm inside a box that you can sell at the Outpost for 1000 pixels. This object always reappears each time you do the mission.  You just need five minutes to find the helmet, so it's a relatively fast way of farming pixels

Answer (score -2):

There are a lot of ways actually. Not dying being one of the most important ones.

You will have to grind your way. Go to the *Alpha Sector* and kill everything you see. That's one way. Put your spare ore in the refinery.

Comment: Hi NinjaBoffin, you haven't added a great deal more than what people have already contributed. You did mention the Alpha Sector as being good for farming Pixels though. Maybe you can go into more detail why that is the case?

Comment: Yeah, sure!
I said the Alpha sector because there a lo of NPC/Monsters for you to kill and they are a doddle. (if you have beta sector weapons+). Then you also get micro dungeons and normal dungeons.

Answer (score -2):

3 steps to fortune.

1. mine cobblestone
2. make rock bricks
3. make dark smooth stone

each 400 cobblestone earns around 20k pixels

Answer (score -2):

My method is to make a **farm** with wheat, bananas, potatoes, ect. Then you will want to  get a **terramart shipping device**. Then, get a **refinery**. You'll also eventually need an **oven**. You can also start an **animal farm** if you want. Selling weapons and blocks that you don't need can aid in this process.

**Here's the strategy:**

- **Tenants** sometimes have **quests**. Completing these is an easy way to earn money.
- Your main source of income will come from producing and selling products. Namely, **food** using your **oven**, and **crops** from your **farm**; you should also produce **weapons** and **armor** using your **refinery**, and use or sell these as you wish.
- If you water your crops frequently and sell off the crops/seeds you don't need, you'll have so much money the game becomes unfun.

I play in frackin universe and some other mods. That shouldn't matter with farming or other things.

Comment: I did not know that what crafting station do you make the stone in?